# How to hide or show element on Button click on Next Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, onclick

I was curious. Consider I have One `SecondActivity` with `ProgressBar` which layout file is

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

and In `MainActivity` I have Two Buttons

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button 1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button 2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Both Button when clicked will open `SecondActivity`.

Now I would Like to show progress bar when button A is clicked but when Button B is clicked, Make the progress Bar invisible in Second Activity.

Below is diagrams illustrating above method that I would like to get.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Just pass boolean to second activity . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass some extras along with the intent while launching your second activity.

When button A is clicked, start the second activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SHOW_PROGRESS", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And when the button B is clicked, launch the second activity without passing any extra in your intent like the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now from your `SecondActivity` receive the intent and show the `ProgressBar` based on the value found from your extras.

```
boolean showProgressBar = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("SHOW_PROGRESS", false);

if(showProgressBar) progressBar.show();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressfaq); on onCreate method , Hence when i used pbar.show();   It gave me error , but instead I sued prab.shown(); and it didn't throwed me any error? does  shown() works instead of show()?